# Function in c that increments a variable

Tags: c, function, increment

I want to develop a function which increments in 1 any variable that you pass by argument. 
I did this, but I know it's wrong:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int incremento(int);

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int x = 1;
    printf("%d", x);
    incremento(x);
    printf("%d", x);

    return 0; 
}

int incremento(int n){
    n++;
    return n; 
}
```

Thanks

Comment: there already is just such an operator.. "++" so not need to try and re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void incremento(int *);

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  int x = 1;
  printf("%d", x);
  incremento(&x);
  printf("%d", x);

  return 0; 
 }

void incremento(int *n){
  (*n)++;
}
```